# Identity Server 4 Running Behind a load Balancer - Refresh Tokens

Tags: identityserver4

I have a token server running based on **IdentityServer4 v 3.1.4** and it does not function behind a load balancer.  For testing purpose I have it running on two servers loginA and loginB. The server loginB refuses to refresh a token issued by loginA and vice versa.  The error in log says **"Client secret validation failed for client: "Test"** and is coming from IdentityServer4.Validation.ClientSecretValidator.

Here is my startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
   var certificate = certificateService.RetrieveCertification(...);

   services.AddIdentityServer(a => a.IssuerUri = "https://login.foo.com")   // both have single issuer name                             
                .AddSigningCredential(certificate) // both use same certificate
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()

                 .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                 {
                     options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                         builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                             sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                 })

                 .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                 {
                     options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                         builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                             sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                     
                     options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                     options.TokenCleanupInterval = 3600;
                     
                 });

 services.AddDataProtection()                
     .PersistKeysToDatabase(new DatabaseKeyManagementOptions           
     {
         ConfigureDbContext = efOptions => efOptions.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
     })
     .SetApplicationName("TEST")                                        // force same name on both
     .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(certificate)                          
 ;

...
}
```

Notes:

- The request body posted to the /connect/token endpoint is the same and fails on server B but succeeds on server A: grant_type: refresh_token  refresh_token: rs43GMUpmNkjXbJTa3OTlL5xh45-qPauq_ep8L3fZt4  scope: openid profile offline_access ....
  client_id: Test
- The endpoint .well-known/openid-configuration on loginA returns:
  {  "issuer": "https://login.foo.com",
  "jwks_uri": "https://loginA.foo.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://loginA.foo.com/connect/authorize",
  ... }
- The endpoint .well-known/openid-configuration on loginB returns:
  { "issuer": "https://login.foo.com",
  "jwks_uri": "https://loginB.foo.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://loginB.foo.com/connect/authorize",
  ... }
- It did not help to set the public origin to "https://login.foo.com" on both servers (AddIdentityServer(a => { a.PublicOrigin = "https://login.foo.com" ....}
- I wanted to get this "simple task" out of the way before upgrading to duende but it is taking more google-time and trial and error that expected :-)

Can anyone see what I am missing?